# Can I use TSA Pre-check security lines to re-enter an intermediate airport during a layover?

Tags: air-travel, layovers, airport-security, tsa-precheck

In a few weeks, I'll be taking a domestic flight that includes a long (3.5 hours) layover. I'd like to leave the airport and have lunch with a friend who lives nearby. I have TSA Pre-check. Assuming I am approved for Precheck for my airport of origin, if I leave the connecting airport during my layover, can I use Precheck lines to reenter the airport there? Or is the pre-check approval specific to the airport of origin?

Answer (score 15):

TSA [pre-check](https://www.tsa.gov/tsa-precheck) will be indicated (or not) on each boarding pass for your journey. Providing you are travelling through an approved airport on an approved airline, you should receive pre-check on all segments of your journey.

Comment: By "approved" are there some airports where you can't get Precheck at all?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai  https://www.tsa.gov/tsa-precheck/map has a map of airports. I presume some smaller airports are not in the list

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Yes, the airports that don't have PreCheck lanes. :) Nowadays, though, those are mostly just small airports and, of course, airports that are not in the U.S.